# How to make people stop hanging their clothes on stairs

Tags: home, personal-care

Recently I slipped when a jacket was hung over the start of the railing of stair and it gave me a bad back pain but home people are not listening or not to hang it there as it is the first thing they see when they enter the house. Is there anything I can put on it so no one hand jackets on it before I or someone else falls?

Comment: If this was somebody else's house, it is not for you to manage their housekeeping. If it is your own house, you can hang the jackets and coats of visitors properly when they arrive.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes it’s my house but the teenage won’t listen I need a way to make that handle unable to hang something as someone can slip again

Comment: A picture would surely help. It depends on the specifics of the area.

Comment: If teenagers won't listen perhaps the best strategy is to move the jackets and coats yourself, to a better place. Otherwise the question is about how to control teenagers which is probably off topic.

Comment: when someone hangs it there, take it up to your room. Now, you have a couple options. 1: Burn it, then they never see it again and think they misplaced it. 2: Put itching powder in the armpits and neck area. 3:  hide it, and hang a sign where  they had it and say that it will be a $50 fine for illegal clothes hanging without a permit. 4: this is the last one, swap it. Get a piece of your clothing that you dont particularly care for, and swap them out. Try to get something similar ish. The, when they leave, see how long it takes for them to notice.

Comment: I have found that all of these work, but my parents yell at me, and now they lock me in the basement when people come over.

Comment: @DripKracken putting itching power is savage . My problem is I cannot yell. Wish I can.

Answer (score 1):

That is actually a matter of education. It is also a matter of having enough and proper places where to store clothes.

I am myself not very well educated in these matters. In the past, my clothes were everywhere. I implemented 2 changes:

1. I decided to be more careful, where I dump my clothes (clean, still wearable, dirty). I am more strict in declaring clothes dirty - it reduces the amount of them in the room.
2. I bought an additional support for coat hangers. It can support coat hangers (with or without clothes), the ends of the bars act like hooks for clothes without coat hangers, and I can store clothes on the bars as if on shelves. The solution is not perfect, but at least it is better. Obviously, the horror is NOT in the living room.

---

In your case, make sure that you have proper storage for jackets near the entrance. Also make sure that the storage is big enough and there are always available hooks / hangers. If it is full of whatever and no clothes can be added, then the stairs rails might be the next best choice.

---

> it is the first thing they see when they enter the house

As I said, the first thing they see should be storage space for clothes / jackets.

> Is there anything I can put on it so no one hand jackets on it before I or someone else falls?

Even better (I already said), add a support for jackets near the entrance. In your case, the best hack is a good solution.

---

Some ideas:

[image] [image]

And imagination is the limit.

Comment: Providing an alternative is a great way to go!